# Extend mirrored LV onto one PV

Tags: storage, lvm

Legend: [Crummy homemade LVM Legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuRQR.png)

Mixed: [Mixed LV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFGZf.png)

I need to add space to an existing 1TB mirrored LV (2 1TB disks) with a new 2TB disk yielding 1+2=3TB.  How do I do this?

I can't move my data to another FS and recreate my LV as a single linear system (4TB) because the 1TB disks are old.

Comment: Do you really need it to be the same LV?

Comment: I prefer it very much

Comment: So that it is still one filesystem, so I can be more free with my directory structure, and split storage across multiple services.  It's just much nicer.